# Pass multiple directories to be opened by ranger in single instance?

Tags: ranger

Is there some way I can pass a "list" of unrelated directories for example:

```
/tmp/
/home/chris
/home/chris/example
```

Into ranger's interface? Similar to what can be done with `ls` with the `-d` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Ranger can open multiple tabs, so you could write a script that transfroms this into:

```
ranger --cmd="cd /tmp/" --cmd="tab_new" --cmd="cd /home/chris" --cmd="tab_new" --cmd="cd /home/chris/example"
```